# How to solve this error message: attempt to select less than one element in OneIndex

Tags: r, functional-programming

I am using `mFD` package to run a code. I am using two datasets to run this code. One is :

[image]

and the another data is:

[image]

My code look like:

```r
alpha_fd_indices <- mFD::alpha.fd.multidim(
  sp_faxes_coord   = sp_faxes_coord [ , c("PC1", "PC2", "PC3", "PC4", "PC5")],
  asb_sp_w         = as.matrix(species),
  ind_vect         = c("fdis", "fmpd", "fnnd", "feve", "fric", "fdiv", "fori", "fspe", "fide"),
  scaling          = TRUE)
```

And the error message is:

```
Error in sp_coord_all_asb[[k]] <- sp_faxes_coord_k : 
  attempt to select less than one element in OneIndex
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: You should include your data in the question in a form we can use, don't post images of it, or nobody can try your code to see what the problem is.

Comment: more reasons: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/)

Answer (score 0):

After struggling with this issue myself I found that the mFD package requires row names for your 'asb_sp_w' matrix here.

From the code for the 'alpha.fd.multidim' function I found that this function runs a loop for each of the community rows of the asb_sp_w matrix but it does this by getting the rownames() from this matrix in the line:
k <- rownames(asb_sp_w)[n].

My workaround was to give each of the rows some fake row names (or your community sample names) and this should allow the function to run without error.

I'm not sure if there is a practical usage for mFD to keep this in the function or not so maybe someone else can comment on this.